# PHP: Populate PDF text fields and let users download customized PDF

Tags: php

There's a need in my application (PHP5/Laravel5) to let users download a PDF file where some of the fields in that PDF should be pre-populated based on a form the user fills online.

Is there some PHP library we can use to provide for that functionality? Doesn't have to be free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tcpdf.
try [TC PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) examples here..